# SDN test environment

Tags: raspberry-pi, simulator, sdn, openflow

I've started learning Software Defined Network and therefore I need a testing environment to understand as well.

Like other network testing environment, I realized that I need a simulator or emulator like GNS3. Recently, I've found OpenFlow vSwitch but couldn't get enough.

The question is, how can I run an SDN testing environment on Linux, Raspberry Pi, etc?

Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup a SDN environment for learning purpose then best tool is mininet. It is very easy to install and setup.you can also find lot of tutorials online.

You can refer this link for its installation and basic understanding : https://konquerouter.wordpress.com/2017/11/24/learning-sdn-software-defined-networking-concept-with-mininet/